# Is there a "<p>" function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble with something that seems so simple, but I can't figure out. In summary, I'm creating a quiz using radio buttons as answer choices, and I am trying to put each answer choice on a new line (or a new paragraph) but for some reason, I am completely unable to.

I have tried a few things:

- Using the .html() command in jQuery
- Putting the question and answer choices in a div in the html portion of the code

Here is what I have in the html part:

```html
<div id="quiz_container">
      <!-- quiz questions will be inserted by code-->
    </div>
```

Here is how the questions will be inserted with jQuery:

```
  for(var j=0;j<questions.length;j++){
    $('#quiz_container').append('<div class="question" id="q' +j+ '"> 
    </div>');
    $('#q'+j).append('<div>'+ questions[j][0]+ '</div>');

    for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
      $('#q'+j).append('<input type="radio" name="q'+j+ '" value="' + 
      questions[j][1][i] +'">'+questions[j][1][i]);
      $("question").html("<p></p>");
    };
  };
```

In this code here,

```html
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    $('#q'+j).append('<input type="radio" name="q'+j+ '"    value="' + 
    questions[j][1][i] +'">'+questions[j][1][i]);
    $("question").html("<p></p>");
};
```

each answer choice should appear on a new line. I am not getting any errors. Instead of

```html
$("question").html("<p></p>");
```

where "question" is the id of the question, what should I do instead so that each answer choice appears on a new line?

(Sorry if this is worded weirdly, if you have any questions just ask and I'll try to answer them)

Comment: Just use CSS, `display:block` should force the next element to a new line. Also, what do you expect `$("question")` to select? There is no `<question>` element.

Comment: 1. `$("question")` tells jQuery to fetch every `<question>` element in the DOM and not an element with id `question`, 2. `.html("<p></p>");` would (only) overwrite the content of the matched elements with an empty paragraph (5 times).

Comment: Can you please create a working snippet with your data so we can't test easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can solve this with just CSS by targeting the radio buttons and using something like `display:block;` as Terry pointed out.

Additionally, there's a [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function in JQuery that will take a DOM node and wrap something around it

So you could do

```
$("question").wrap("<p></p>");
```

You could also just put the `<p>` in when you generate the input

```
$('#q'+j).append('<p><input type="radio" name="q'+j+ '"    value="' + 
    questions[j][1][i] +'">'+ questions[j][1][i] + '</p>');
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't have the best understanding of jQuery and wasn't sure how HTML worked with jQuery. This makes a lot more sense now and I will use this knowledge to my advantage in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Not jQuery answer:

You can use the `<br>` element in html, or use the following code to create one using pure JavaScript:

```js
var br = document.createElement('BR');
document.body.appendChild(br);

var p = document.createElement('P');
p.innerHTML = 'Hi2';
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

```html
<p>Hi</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.html` changes the entire html of the question element.

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
let answer = $("<p>").text("*answer goes here*");
$("#question").append(answer);
```